# Html5 cache manifest and Post form

Tags: html, caching, manifest

I'm working with cache manifest and im new in this topic, but i made some testing with static pages, but now i wanna try with a page with a form that send data to another page that use a post variable, i add the pages in cache manifest but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

What does not work? The pages don't get cached?

Or doesn't the new page resolves the variables? In that case it's normal because POST variables could only become parsed by a server. And with GET its a hell of getting all URLs into the manifest.
If that is your problem: use local storage instead to transfer the variables from one page to another:
[HTML5 Local Storage – Complete Guide](http://php-html.net/tutorials/html5-local-storage-guide/)